# 100% accuracy in random forest and 94% accuracy in KNN?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, knn

I was going to classify into the following dataset.

[Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/rodolfomendes/abalone-dataset/kernels)

I achieved amazingly high results (too high) and I think I had to do something wrong.

I'm trying to make a clasification for the age group based on the rest of the characteristics. I know there is a large correlation between variables and I will have to fix it all but for now I wanted to use everything as dependent variables.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

dataset = pd.read_csv('abalone.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1:].values

dataset["Sex"]= dataset["Sex"].replace('M', 0)
dataset["Sex"]= dataset["Sex"].replace('F', 1)
dataset["Sex"]= dataset["Sex"].replace('I', 2)

dataset["Age group"]= dataset["Age group"].replace('young abalone', 0)
dataset["Age group"]= dataset["Age group"].replace('middle-aged abalone', 1)
dataset["Age group"]= dataset["Age group"].replace('mature abalone', 2)
dataset["Age group"]= dataset["Age group"].replace('senior abalone', 3)

dataset['Age group'] = dataset['Age group'].astype(int).astype(float)
dataset['Rings'] = dataset['Rings'].astype(int).astype(float)
dataset['Sex'] = dataset['Sex'].astype(int).astype(float)

X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1:].values

# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()

# Avoiding the Dummy Variable Trap
X = X[:, 1:]

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

# Fitting Random Forest Classification to the Training set
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 10, criterion = 'entropy', random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

# Making the Confusion Matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
cm

## KNN

# Fitting K-NN to the Training set
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
classifier2 = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 7, metric = 'minkowski', p = 2)
classifier2.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier2.predict(X_test)

# Making the Confusion Matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
cm
```

I put all the code because I don't know exactly what went wrong.

I haven't checked yet other accuracy measures because the confusion matrix itself says something probably went wrong

Comment: Sorry I cannot reproduce tour code, the variable `'Age group'` does not exist in the original dataset. The dataset you linked doesn't seem to be the same as the one you are using in the code.

Comment: Did you leave `rings` in your training data? If so, then the problem is data leakage. The `rings` variable is an exact proxy for the `age_groups` target.

Comment: I completely agree with G.Anderson... `Age group` should be a derived variable of `rings`. Get rid of it and rerun